# Unable to solve 503 error for POST Request (express)

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, fetch-api, http-status-code-503

Whenever my frontend (React) runs at localhost:3000 and my backend (express) runs locally on localhost:8282, I get a 503 error and am able to see expected results.
My fronten has been deployed at netlify and backend in heroku. I run into cors error and some other weird error that I am unable to solve. Here are the code snippets:

getting the following errors:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://projectname.herokuapp.com/payment' from
origin 'https://projectnamee.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
POST https://projectname.herokuapp.com/payment net::ERR_FAILED 503
```

fetch call in frontend:

```
    const backend_api = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? 'https://projectname.herokuapp.com/payment' : 'http://localhost:8282/payment';
    const purchase = token => {
        let product = purchaseProduct
        const body = {
            token,
            product
        }
        const headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
        }
        return fetch(backend_api, {
            method: "POST",
            headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(response => {
            console.log("Response ", response)
            const {status} = response;
            console.log("STATUS ", status)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

backend index.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require("cors")
const express = require("express")
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SEC_KEY)
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const app = express();

// middleware
app.use(express.json())

// I tried a lot of variations of this, none worked
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}))
  
// routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Works here")
})

app.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
    const {product, token} = req.body;
    console.log("Product", product)
    console.log("price", product.price)
    console.log("email", token.email)
    const idempotencyKey = uuidv4()

    return stripe.customers.create({
        email: token.email,
        source: token.id
    }).then(customer => {
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount: product.price * 100,
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: customer.id,
            receipt_email: token.email,
            description: `Purchase of ${product.name}`,
            shipping: {
                name: token.card.name,
                address: {
                    country: token.card.address_country
                }
            }
        }, {idempotencyKey})
    }).then(result => res.status(200).json(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})


// listen
const port = process.env.PORT || 8282
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: access control headers are for the response, not the request.

Comment: I think you should not return stripe.customers.create. Rather calling it and in the then block res.json should work. Your cors settings seems to be fine, just define it before app.use(express.json())

Comment: The session cookie from `herokuapp.com` may be considered third-party by your frontend on `netlify.app` and hence blocked by your browser. This would cause the request to be unauthenticated and hence fail.